# What type of public key is this?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a public key, and the only way I know how to describe it to other programmer is that it's a xml public key. This description is not exactly the most defined.

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>
        uno9DsYcaZ1yAqY20nIM+YjYjjFsGx0DYm7lBGxbmVLLZTYc9MaI0Br+
        8ElcuZVVNRmGeVBlkcHT3JpMDf/fiWSho6o0pRhQZmnG4RZtCWnGjFTV+
        QWBYcuTGoQFKOtsrGqG16XwL2hPxqYW/7nzBVgAGe6myG3hMou8P4DSpjk=
    </Modulus> 
    <Exponent>
        AQAB
    </Exponent> 
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Is there another term for a key as such other than a generic term like "XML key"?

This key was generated by C#. Most likely with the command rsa.toxml()

Comment: It's an XML public key formatted more or less according to the [W3C XML Security](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) specifications. Microsoft just decided to format RSA keys that way, probably just to spite me because they know I really hate XML.

Comment: So the most defined way to go about googling about it, is indeed just as an XML RSA key?